# Integral of $\int f^2(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can we write the integral

$$\int f^2(x)\,dx$$

in terms of $f(x)$, $x$ and $\int f(x)\,dx$?

I've tried solving the integral by parts, but I can only end up with an equation of the form $0=0$. Maybe it is that it's not possible to do what I'm asking, I don't know...

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "in terms of $f(x), x,$ and $\int f(x) dx$"? Do you mean linear combinations of these? Products of these? Linear combinations of products?

Comment: $\int f^2(x)\, dx = f(x)f^\prime(x)-\int f(x)f^\prime(x)\, dx$ is the best that I know of

Comment: @ckefa I mean, like, with algebraic expressions of these. Not just products or linear combinations or whatever. You could youse, for example $\ln(f(x))$ or $\sqrt{\int f(x)\,dx}$, or whatever, but not $f'(x)$. As I said, it is maybe impossible to do so, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: There is no such way. For example, consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\log x}$. Then $$\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\log\log x+\mathsf{C},$$ but $$\int f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{x\log x}-\operatorname{Ei}(-\log x)+\mathsf{C},$$ where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the exponential integral which is proven to be non-elementary. There is no way to write $\operatorname{Ei}(-\log x)$ as a finite elementary closed-form expression involving $f(x)=1/x\log x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function for which I think this is not true: let $f(x) = \arctan x.$ Then, $f(x), x$, and
$$\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x = x\arctan x - \frac{1}{2}\ln|1+x^{2}|$$ are all elementary functions.

So, to use your words, any "algebraic expression" (which I take from your comment to mean taking sums, products, and composing with elementary functions) of $x, f(x), \int f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ must also be an elementary function.

But as seen in this answer: [How to integrate $\arctan^2(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201153/how-to-integrate-arctan2x), the integral
$$\int f^{2}(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int \arctan^{2}x \mathrm{d}x$$ inolves a Dilogarithm, which is nonelementary, so there is no hope for an "algebraic expression" involving $x, f(x), \int f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ that equals $\int f^{2}(x)\mathrm{d}x$.